# Colorear elemento de menu al scrollear por la pagina

Tags: javascript, css, html5

En mi sitio tengo la etiqueta `nav` y en su interior lo siguiente

```
                    <ul>
                        <li class="current">
                            <a href="#inicio" data-scrollto="#inicio">
                                <div>Inicio</div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#trabajos" data-scrollto="#trabajos">
                                <div>Trabajos</div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#about" data-scrollto="#about">
                                <div>Quienes Somos</div>
                            </a>
                        </li>


                        <li>
                            <a href="#msj" data-scrollto="#msj">
                                <div>Mensajeanos</div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

> Hay una clase `current` que le dá un color de fondo distinto al elemento de la lista (en este caso a Inicio). Yo quisiera que esta clase se vaya colocando en los distintos elementos del menú (en el que corresponda) cuando hago scroll por la pagina y voy pasando por las distintas secciones.

Alguna idea de como podría hacerlo? Muchas gracias

Comment: Tienes que saber cada uno de los bloques cual es su coodenada superior `scrollTop` property, y despues por javascript añades un listener para el scroll. Ahí capturas el scroll de la pantalla y según el resultado cambias la clase al elemento que corresponda. Espero pilles la idea. saludos!

Comment: ahi va! Existia una propiedad que te devuelve la posicion del ``section``!! Era lo que necesitaba :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
//IntersectionObserver permite configurar una función callback 
//que es llamada cada vez que un elemento, llamado target, 
//intersecta con otro, bien el viewport o un elemento específico

var observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries) {
 if(entries[0].isIntersecting)
 {
           asignarClase(entries[0].target);
         }

//el valor threshold indica que porcentaje del elemento debe estar 
//visible 0 = esta en linea con el viewport, 1 = esta totalmente visible
//0.1 se muestra el 10% etc

}, { threshold: [0.1] });

//agregar aquí los selectores de los elementos a observar en el scroll

observer.observe(document.querySelector("#inicio"));
observer.observe(document.querySelector("#trabajos"));
observer.observe(document.querySelector("#about"));



function asignarClase(target){
//obtener los elementos del menu
var elementosMenu = document.querySelectorAll("ul li a");

//actualizar clase current
elementosMenu.forEach(e => {
  //extraer el valor del  href del elemento del menu
  valorhref = e.href.split("#")[1]
  //si el valor del href es igual al id del target agregar
  //clase current
 if(valorhref === target.id){
    e.parentNode.classList.add("current");
 }else{
  //si el valor no es igual remover clase current
  e.parentNode.classList.remove("current");
 }
 
})




}
```

```css
.current{
     background-color:lightblue;
}

.main{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="current">
       <a href="#inicio" data-scrollto="#inicio">
           <div>Inicio</div>
       </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#trabajos" data-scrollto="#trabajos">
           <div>Trabajos</div>
        </a>
     </li>
     <li>
         <a href="#about" data-scrollto="#about">
            <div>Quienes Somos</div>
         </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#msj" data-scrollto="#msj">
            <div>Mensajeanos</div>
        </a>
      </li>
  </ul>
                    
<div  class="main">

<div id="inicio" style="background-color:yellow; height:300px">
</div>

<div id="trabajos" style="background-color:blue;height:300px">
</div>

<div id="about" style="background-color:red;height:300px">
</div>




</div>
```

Comment: Impecable, muchas gracias

Comment: Por favor considera argumentar un poco tu respuesta. Responder sólo con código se considera de baja calidad. Puedes repasar [answer]. Saludos

Comment: Los comentarios están dentro del código.